# Error in getTokenAccountBalance (failed to get token account balance), when quickly buying/selling

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, spl-token-program, raydium

I am attempting to sell tokens immediately after purchasing them (in few seconds), but I am encountering an error when trying to retrieve the balance/token account for the swap. I have used both methods, `getTokenAccountBalance and getTokenAccountsByOwner`, but I am consistently getting the same error ("cannot find token account" from baseMint or "failed to get token account balance" from tokeAccount).

I have observed that the code works fine if I set a longer delay for the sell-swap, such as 20 seconds or more. I suspect that this issue may be related to -> Finalized (MAX confirmations). So I cant getTokenBalance until Tx is completely Finalized, which takes over 10-15 seconds.

Is there any way to use RPC methods (e.x. to check token balance) before TX is finalized?

```
async function buy(
  accountId: PublicKey,
  accountData: LiquidityStateV4,
): Promise<void> {
  const tokenAccount = existingTokenAccounts.get(
    accountData.baseMint.toString(),
  );

  if (!tokenAccount) {
    logger.error(`No token account found for mint: ${accountData.baseMint}`);
    return;
  }

  logger.info(`CreatePoolKeys for ${accountId}`);
  tokenAccount.poolKeys = createPoolKeys(
    accountId,
    accountData,
    tokenAccount.market!,
  );
  logger.info(`Create Liquidity Pool for ${accountId}`);
  const { innerTransaction, address } = Liquidity.makeSwapFixedInInstruction(
    {
      poolKeys: tokenAccount.poolKeys,
      userKeys: {
        tokenAccountIn: quoteTokenAssociatedAddress,
        tokenAccountOut: tokenAccount.address,
        owner: wallet.publicKey,
      },
      amountIn: quoteAmount.raw,
      minAmountOut: 0,
    },
    tokenAccount.poolKeys.version,
  );

  logger.info(`Get latest blockhash for ${accountId}`);
  const latestBlockhash = await solanaConnection.getLatestBlockhash({
    commitment: commitment,
  });
  logger.info(`Create TransactionMessage for ${accountId}`);
  const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
    payerKey: wallet.publicKey,
    recentBlockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
    instructions: [
      ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({ units: 400000 }),
      ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({ microLamports: 3000000 }),
      createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotentInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey,
        tokenAccount.address,
        wallet.publicKey,
        accountData.baseMint,
      ),
      ...innerTransaction.instructions,
    ],
  }).compileToV0Message();
  logger.info(`Sign TransactionMessage for ${accountId}`);
  const transaction = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
  transaction.sign([wallet, ...innerTransaction.signers]);
  logger.info(`Send TransactionMessage for ${accountId}`);
  const signature = await solanaConnection.sendRawTransaction(
    transaction.serialize(),
    {
      maxRetries: 20,
      skipPreflight: true,
    },
  );

  setTimeout(() => sell(tokenAccount, accountData), 3000);

}


async function sell(
  accountId: PublicKey,
  accountData: LiquidityStateV4,
): Promise<void> {
  const tokenAccount = existingTokenAccounts.get(accountData.baseMint.toString());

  if (!tokenAccount) {
    return;
  }
    try {

//ERROR appears in this line
      const balanceResponse = (await solanaConnection.getTokenAccountBalance(tokenAccount.address)).value.amount;  

      if (balanceResponse !== null && Number(balanceResponse) > 0) {

////////////
      throw new SolanaJSONRPCError(
            ^
SolanaJSONRPCError: failed to get token account balance: Invalid param: could not find account
    at Connection.getTokenAccountBalance (C....\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:3352:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: -32602,
  data: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fixes it, but make sure to make Solana requests with the same commitment, eg `confirmed`.

In the `buy` method you do this when calling `getLatestBlockhash`, but the `getTokenAccountBalance` doesn't.